# Help with proof regarding the interior of a Set

Tags: real-analysis

Let A, B $\subset$ R and let $x_{0}$ $\in$ R such that $x_{0}$ $\in$ int(A) and $x_{0}$ $\in$ int(B).
Show that $x_{0}$ $\in$ int(A$\cap$B)

Any insight would be helpful.
P.D i know conceptually is easy to grasp but i dont know how to formalize it

Comment: As stated this is trivial. Maybe the right handside should be $\mathrm{int}(A \cap B)$ ?

Comment: Also, when you fix your question, include the definition of your goal.

Comment: @rubikscube09 if it where in that form how would you prove it

Comment: Do you know the definition of the statement $x_0\in\int(C)$ (in other words, the definition of the interior of a set)?

Comment: i know that if xo in the int(A) then there exists r>0 such that (x-r,x+r) contain in A, it would be the same x0 in b i suppose that then i would have that (x-r,x+r) contain A intersection B would imply that xo belong to the interior of the intersection of A and B

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\Int}{\operatorname{int}}
$
**Hints:**

- Recall that $x \in \Int(S)$ if and only if there exists some $T \subseteq S$ which is an open neighborhood of $x$.
- Since $x_0$ is in both $\Int(A)$ and $\Int(B)$, we can find such sets $A_0,B_0$ for each of $A,B$, respectively.
- Observe that the intersection $A_0 \cap B_0$ contains $x_0$, and is an open neighborhood of $x_0$ contained within $A \cap B$. Reapply the definition of interior in this light.

I'll leave the justifications up to you.